# How to get font file from windows phone

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, fonts, xamarin.forms

I'm creating library in Xamarin platform and I need to get device (android,iOS and windows) font file.
In android I can get the font files from`/system/fonts` folder.

**Android:**

```
string[] fontfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("/system/fonts");
```

Can anyone share your idea to get font file from the Windows device?.

Thanks in Advance.

Sasi.

Comment: you need to bundle it with your app in any folder

Comment: Why did you need get the font file? You need set the size font ?

Answer (score 0):

> How to get font file from windows phone

You can't get system font file in Windows Phone, but you can get the system font. Refer to [ptallett's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/theuxblog/2016/07/10/enumerating-installed-fonts-using-sharpdx-directwrite-and-xaml-in-a-windows-10-store-app-uwp/), do the following steps :

1. In order to get system font in UWP, we must use `DirectX`, install these `NuGet` pacakges into your project :

   - SharpDX
   - SharpDX.Direct2D1
2. `GetFontFiles()` will return all system fonts.

   ```
   public class GetFont : FontDemo.IGetFont
   {
       public string[] GetFontFiles()
       {
           var fontList = new List<string>();
           var factory = new SharpDX.DirectWrite.Factory();
           var fontCollection = factory.GetSystemFontCollection(false);
           var familyCount = fontCollection.FontFamilyCount;

           for (int i = 0; i < familyCount; i++)
           {
               var fontFamily = fontCollection.GetFontFamily(i);
               var familyNames = fontFamily.FamilyNames;
               int index;

               if (!familyNames.FindLocaleName(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, out index))
               {
                   if (!familyNames.FindLocaleName("en-us", out index))
                   {
                       index = 0;
                   }
               }
               string name = familyNames.GetString(index);
               fontList.Add(name);
           }
           return fontList.ToArray();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Using [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/) in your `PCL` to get the result :

   ```
   string[] fontfiles = DependencyService.Get<IGetFont>().GetFontFiles();
   ```